# symfony2/Doctrine Entity with multiple tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I map and implement Setters/Getters and the annotations for one **entity** that has it's information in multiple tables?

For example we have these tables :

- Product (id, name, ctime)
- Prices (id, price)
- Sold (id, amount)
- Bought (id, amount)
- Revenue (id, revenue)
- MarketShare (id, share)
- Stock (id, amount)
- LastEdit(id, datetime)

They all relate by id.
Product entity is something like this:

```
class Product {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $sold;
    private $bought;
    private $revenue;
    private $share;
    private $stock;
    private $lastEdit;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all properties that will have only one value you don't have to use separate table (entity) for that, use simple properties (variables) and `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` will create all required getters and setters.

If you still need (for some reason) to have all information in separate tables in that case create entities for all properties (Prices, Sold, Revenue, ...) and configure OneToOne or OneToMany (depending on whether you want to have single value or multiple values for that property) links between product and related entities.

For example:

```
class Product {
  ...

  /**
   * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Price", mappedBy="product")
   */
  protected $prices;

  /**
   * @var Stock
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Stock", mappedBy="product")
   */
  protected $stock;
  ...
}
```

Now, the Stock entity with OneToOne relation:

```
class Stock {
  ...

  /**
   * @var integer
   * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="integer")
   */
  protected $amount;

  /**
   * @var Product
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="stock")
   */
  protected $product;

  ...
}
```

And Price entity with ManyToOne relation:

```
class Price {
  ...

  /**
   * @var float
   * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
   */
  protected $price;

  /**
   * @var Product
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="prices")
   */
  protected $product;

  ...
}
```

And as I mentioned earlier `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` will create all required getters and setters based on the configuration.

NOTE: Keep in mind that with this configuration child entities with OneToOne relation will be updated with additional field - **product_id**. OneToMany will not alter your schema.

Hope that helps

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much, it was indeed helpful. In this approach, would doctrine make too much queries for getting the information? Second question : if I persist an object that has no price, would it create an empty row in prices table?

Comment: Because prices property in the Product is OneToMany relation, when you will save product with empty `prices` list, nothing will be created in the database. On the other hand, if you will choose to create OneToOne relations for other entities (properties) you will have to create them in the constructor, manually or using cascade. If you will not so that accessing these properties will throw exception. And accessing them later will be performed with additional queries to the database. If you dont want this then use regular properties (columns) as I suggested earlier.